# Is it possible to import files from one SVN repository to another using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, repository

I have several separate SVN repositories locally on my machine and I use only the TortoiseSVN client functionality without an SVN server backend.

Now I want to merge these repositories **while keeping the revision history of individual files**. Is that possible with with TortoiseSVN alone or even SVN?

**Edit:** It seems like what I want to accomplish is best done using [svn:externals](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/132-svnexternals.html) and keeping one repository for each project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging two repositories is possible (even if you don't use a server).  See [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375869/subversion-merging-repositories).

Comment: Great link, thanks. Missed it when searching for previous questions. I think I'll go for the svn:externals solution.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know if there's a way to do this with existing tools**, however theoretically it would be possible if the repositories have different paths (of course they can't overleap), and if you can loose commit number for the added repositories.

This would be possible by replicating each commit of the source repositories into the new master target repository.

Comment: By "replicating", do you mean manually first check out each revision starting from the beginning and then successively commit each new version? Or did you mean something else? With 1000 revisions, "manually" is not a beautiful word...  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, of course I don't mean manually, it would be insane :-) I mean using an automated tool or script that imports each commit from the source to the destination repository. Of course, there will be not correspondence between commit numbers (the only way to track it is to commit description the original commit number), however I don't know if there's already such a tool, but it is technically possible.