# Move SVN repository to folder in another repository

Tags: svn, svn-repository

I have two SVN repostitories:

Project A

- trunk
- tags
- branches

Project B

- trunk
- tags
- branches

Now I wan't to reach this structure:

Projects

- Project A

  - trunk
  - tags
  - branches
- Project B

  - trunk
  - tags
  - branches

I have dumped the two repositories using

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repository-name.dmp
```

How can I restore them to the above structure?

**EDIT:
This solves my problem!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3141938/885683**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (assuming you want to keep history) is to just merge one repository into the other. So let's assume you keep the repository for Project A, then you can dump the repository for Project B and merge that to the repository for Project A.  See [this link](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#multi-merge) for more details.

If you don't want to keep history, just import the most recent code.

edit:
I haven't tried this myself, but it should be something like this. (Backup your repo before trying.)

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repob > repob.dmp
svnadmin load /path/to/repoa < repob.dmp
```

Comment: I want to keep history. I'm aware of the command `svnadmin load` but I don't see how I should use it here.